# Is Javascript's normalize function supported in react native?

Tags: validation, react-native, normalize

I am currently working on a react native application and am doing some file name sanitization. I've noticed that certain file uploads have been failing for characters with accents in the names. I started removing the special characters with the normalize function, since the regex isn't enough by itself, however the function seems to not be supported on android.

Example:

```
sanitizeFileName(fileName) {
    let encodedFileName = fileName || "upload";
    encodedFileName = encodedFileName.normalize('NFD');
    encodedFileName = encodedFileName.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'_');
    return encodedFileName;
}
```

and this is the error is thrown an android:

`TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'o.normalize('NFD')'`

The above function works as expected on iOS for some reason. Looking at the documentation for [normalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) it says it is supported in Node.js

I'm wondering maybe the 'NFD' option isn't supported or something like that?

The above function does work however if I remove the `normalize` part...

It also **works** with the normalize function in debug mode.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem, it works on Android in debug mode but stopped when not in debug mode, which makes little sense to me.

I ended up using [unorm](https://github.com/walling/unorm#readme).

```
yarn add unorm
```

imported module

```
import unorm from 'unorm';
```

Then replace **encodedFileName.normalize('NFD')** for

```
unorm.nfd(encodedFileName);
```

Works fine on Android and iOS. I hope it can help others.

Comment: Awesome I'll look into this, thanks! As for the debug / release thing, apparently debug mode uses the computers JS engine vs the devices. Just found that out the hard way recently...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation on the link you provided, it says it is not compatible with Android WebView.

Comment: But maybe it gets converted into a WebView when it's transpiled, I don't know.  Maybe you could look at this node package as an alternative.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalize

Comment: Thanks I might end up using that, the weird thing is it runs in debug mode just not release mode.